# Is The Executioner in Gotham TV show a pun on Marvel character of same name?

Tags: character, comic-adaptation, gotham

In *Gotham* season 3, we see Nathaniel Barnes' full transformation into The Executioner,:

[image]

This character doesn't look like any DC character I know but like a marvel [character of same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executioner_(comics))

[image]

And blade on Nathaniel Barnes' hand reminded me Marvel's The Executioner Axe. Is it a pun on marvel character or inspired from it? Or it's a big stretch?

Comment: Big difference I think. Marvel's Executioner is although be a villain, had no similarity with Barnes except the name. to quote Wikia "Barnes was a strict by the book law enforcer until he became infected with the the Tetch blood virus he went insane and gained anger-induced superhuman abilities, he took on the role of The Executioner, to murder guilty criminals against the law but was brought down by the efforts of Jim Gordon and was sent to Arkham Asylum."  Marvel's -> Wikipedia "Skurge, an Asgardian, was originally depicted as a supervillain who wielded a magic double-bladed battle axe"

Comment: @Vishwa I didn't said there origin are similar but how it look like a  ripoff

Comment: The way they looked like or wearing the axe part?

Comment: Kind of both and names

Comment: In the comics, Batman and Robin fought a criminal who used the identity of the Executioner. His real name was Willy Hooker and worked at a carnival. To make an extra buck, he would break criminals out of jail and then kill them so that he could collect the reward money. He only appeared in one issue: Detective Comics #191 (January 1953). ([source](http://comicbook.com/dc/2017/05/12/gotham-exclusive-barnes-executioner/))

Comment: @Tim in presence of no other answer, it can work as an answer too with little more elaboration